# Dependency is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with internal version provided by android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I keep getting the error below as I try to run my app. Im trying to connect the java-twilio jar to work with my app. I have tried to search for a fix everywhere but to no avail. Any help would be great thanks

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>       Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
>       Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2-beta'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.5.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0-beta'
    compile(group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-notifications-handler', version: '1.0.1', ext: 'jar')
    compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:3.4.5' <--- where jar is added
}
```

Comment: Was `com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:3.4.5` the last one you added? If you are not sure, post this output `gradlew dependencies`.

Comment: Yes it is the last one i added in

Comment: Are you getting any other errors? Notice that that is just a warning, and unless it is causing other errors, you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @KeithTuffy all this means is that a Android version from the Android.jar is being used instead of the one located in `com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:3.4.5`.

Comment: Its ok now, I think its an incompatibility with the sdk and android studio. Iv moved away from that and made a direct http post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making a simple http request to the twilio web service rather than using the dependency to make the request for me...worked perfect